# KeyboardAvoidingView is pushing up content with excessive padding in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am having trouble getting the KeyboardAvoidingView to work properly. For a similar screen it is working smoothly, however, for another it is pushing up content way too far up on the screen, adding excessive amounts of space in between. Any fix?

[image]

code:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
         {this.props.signNameErr &&
            (<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.props.errMessage}</Text>)
          }
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.formInput}
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
          returnKeyType="next"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={(full_name)=> this.setState({full_name})}
          value={this.state.fullname}
          placeholder="Enter Full Name"
          />
          {this.props.signEmailErr &&
            (<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.props.errMessage}</Text>)
          }
        <TextInput
          style={styles.formInput}
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
          returnKeyType="next"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={(email)=> this.setState({email})}
          value={this.state.email}
          placeholder="Enter Email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          />
           {this.props.signPwErr &&
            (<Text style={{color: 'red'}}>{this.props.errMessage}</Text>)
          }
        <TextInput
          style={styles.formInput}
          placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
          underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
          returnKeyType="next"
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={(password)=> this.setState({password})}
          secureTextEntry={this.state.togglePW}
          value={this.state.password}
          placeholder="Create Password (Min. 6 Char)"
          />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.handleSignup}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SIGN UP</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View >
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set the padding, you can even set for android and ios

```
import {KeyboardAvoidingView,Platform,} from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView 
  behavior='padding'
  keyboardVerticalOffset={
  Platform.select({
     ios: () => 0,
     android: () => 200
  })()
}>
   ...content...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Just an example, try it out and set how you like. The padding can also be a negative value like -300.

Comment: @Brunaine I follow ur code but I see some more gab at the end it's cover inputs

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
 style={styles.container}
   behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
 >
```

Though, I had to import Platform from 'react-native'